# VB. NET: System.NullReferenceException occurred

Tags: vb.net

I'm back again, I just cant figure out the solution here. Can someone lend me a hand with this? I'm having a problem about "Setting of Object reference to an instance of an object".

PS: I read some links here that is connected to this problem but still no luck. Here is the link "[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)"

It said, we must check and fill the variable to anything just make sure the variable has a value. But in my case, my variable has a value, why is it returning "NullReference" error ?

Thanks Guys.

BELOW IS MY CODE. (Not the entire module just only the procedure)

```
    Private m_imp As Object ' We delegate the details of horz or vert to this class

    Public Sub addWidget1(ByRef widget As Object, ByRef minExtent As Object)

        m_widget1 = widget
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object widget.ZOrder. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
        widget.ZOrder()
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object m_imp.minExtent1. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object minExtent. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
        m_imp.minExtent1 = minExtent ' <---- HERE IS THE ERROR
    End Sub
```

ERROR: System.NullReferenceException occurred

[image: screen shot]

PS: CODE CALLING THE FUNCTION'S ERROR.

```
   Private Sub initGUI(ByRef splitter As clsSplitLayout, ByRef navpane As clsPaneNav, ByRef contentpane As clsPaneContent, ByRef detailpane As clsPaneDetail)

    Dim hsplit As New clsSplitLayout
    With hsplit
        .SplitType = clsSplitLayout.SplitterType.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT
        .createSplitBar("bar1", Me)
        .addWidget1(contentpane, 2000)  '<--- HERE'S HOW I CALL THE FUNCTION THAT HAS ERROR.
        .addWidget2(detailpane, 2000)
    End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: show code where you assign a value to `m_imp`

Comment: Where do you assign anything to `m_imp`?  That's what `null` (`Nothing` in VB) means, it's a reference type which was never assigned.

Comment: You should enable `Option Strict`; your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that let's us pin point the answer. This is therefore a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. You should delete this question or add the code that let's us see the problem.

Comment: I know it is duplicate. Did you see my link above? As i said, i dont have a variable nothing as stated in the link you guys have given. There's value "2000" there (see image).

Comment: Hi Igor and David, yeah, I never assigned m_imp. it is an object.. The equivalent value here is "nothing". how can i assign it? I just converted my VB6 to VB.NET and this is the result. I'm just debugging it. Please respect, specially the one that said NONSENSE. Thanks Guys :))

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict too and fix the errors the compiler points out.  Study the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.NullReferenceException occurs when you're reading a variable that has n value in it.

In your case, m_imp is defined but it has no value.

Before you access m_imp, m_imp must have a value.

Comment: Yes, can you give me a sample/generic value?  I really don't know, I just migrated my VB6 to VB.NET. :salute: